# How do I redirect a bad referer using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I am getting spam from a bot that is faking Google image searches and I want to redirect all traffic from that referer to somewhere else, how do I do it?

The referer string of the bad traffic always has http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl at the beginning with a much longer string after the imgurl part.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://redirecthere.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The apache rewrite engine uses Regular Expressions and a ? in a regular expression means that the char before is optional. So you have to escape the ?
This one should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.google.com/imgres\?imgurl  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://redirecthere.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Tried this and doesn't work, I have plenty of rules that do work I just can't get this one working at all.

Comment: for debugging try to activate the redirect log on look what happen on which point
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog